# How to delete an architecture called “1386” (a typo) in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, permissions, architecture, ubuntu-15.04

After typing:

```
dpkg --remove-architecture 1386
```

I get the message:

```
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied
```

1386 is a typo, I'm trying to rid myself of in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command as root:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386
```

*(putting my comment in an answer)*